# how we get end position of a progress bar /seek bar?

Tags: android

i create a audio player and wanna play a audio several times but once it complete 1st time, the progress bar get stuck at the end.i tried to get the last position of progress bar by

```
boolean atEnd = audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().getDuration()
                - audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().getCurrentPosition() == 0;
```

but it gives false every time.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply set the `OnCompletionListener`[1].

```
audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().
       setOnCompletionListener(
            new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "end reached");
                  }
            }
       );
```

[1]

> Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media source has
>   been reached during playback.

Comment: Did you forget the link? FYI: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

Comment: thanks for your answers..
and i found that...the "getduration()" is not working on run time because i download the audio file from a url at run time..
and also  "setOnCompletionListener" work perfectly for me...

Comment: Thx ur ans helped me.I wanted to achieve if(player.getCurrentPosition()>=player.getDuration()){} but player.getCurrentPosition() never reaches player.getDuration(). Why?